# Construction of a $K(\pi,1)$-space?

Tags: homotopy-theory

My colleague suggested a proof of a fact which I have hard time to believe. Since I am not a topologist by training I am asking it here.

Consider any CW-complex structure on the $d$-dimensional sphere $S^d$. Let $K$ be $S^d$ with all strata of codimension at least 2 removed, i.e. we keep just $d$ and $(d-1)$-dimensional strata of the complex.

Claim. $K$ can be contracted to a graph, i.e. $K$ is a $K(\pi,1)$-space where $\pi$ is a free group.

Comment: This question really belongs on math.stackexchange; I would be happy to answer it there. But this site is for questions of current mathematical research.

Comment: If the question is reposted and answered on MSE, it would be useful to add a link here. Otherwise, since it has 5 upvotes, one could also answer it here, in my opinion.